# Restrict posting to admin-only in group chat

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there any option in WhatsApp that restricts posting messages by admin only? Others should not able post, but they should able to read the post.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible because the setting does not exist.
Maybe you coud broadcast to these people or try a alternative app.

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature might soon be introduced, under the name of **Restricted Groups**:

> The Restricted Groups setting can only be enabled by group admins.
>
> Switching it on disables all chat functionality for non-admins – they
>   won’t be able to send text messages, images, videos, GIFs, documents
>   or voice messages, or share their location.
>
> Admins, meanwhile, will be able to continue chatting as normal.
>   Everyone else will simply have to read their messages in silence.
>
> If a non-admin really wants to get a word in, they can do so by using
>   the Message Admin button.
>
> However, the message will need to be approved by the admin before
>   going through to the rest of the group.

https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/whatsapp-restricted-groups-admin-stop-messages-silence-everyone-else-mute-a8086546.html